# What is default duration of CacheOutput() middleware in ASP.NET Core 7.0, .NET 7.0

Tags: c#, .net-7.0, c#-11.0, asp.net-core-7.0

Today I learned **CacheOutput** middleware in **ASP.NET Core 7.0 (.NET 7.0)**. I have researched many times but I can't find a default cache duration.

```
app.MapGet("/cached", () => DateTime.Now.ToString()).CacheOutput();
```

What is the default cache duration of **CacheOutput()** middleware ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs "Configure multiple endpoints or pages" section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/output?view=aspnetcore-7.0#configure-multiple-endpoints-or-pages):

> If an expiration time isn't specified, it defaults to one minute.